# sitemap.xml and serviceworker.js are location-sensitive files. But sensitive to the location in the request path or to the actual filesystem location?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, xml-sitemap, .well-known

I really like the idea of using `.htaccess` rewrite rules in combination with the `/.well-known/` folder for keeping my webspace tidy and coherently / consistently organised.

For instance, I know that webcrawlers (and humans)

- will look for my `robots.txt` in the root folder; and
- will look for my `security.txt` in the `/.well-known/` folder.

This means that files which *ought* to be near each other would, conventionally, be separated.

### The Setup

**But** I also know I can rewrite requests using `.htaccess`, such that I can rewrite a request for:

- `/robots.txt` to `/.well-known/protocols/robots.txt`
- `/.well-known/security.txt` to `/.well-known/protocols/security.txt`

Great. Now *all* the protocols:

- [`robots.txt`](https://www.robotstxt.org/)
- [`security.txt`](https://securitytxt.org/)
- [`ads.txt`](https://iabtechlab.com/ads-txt-about/)
- [`sellers.json`](https://iabtechlab.com/sellers-json/)
- [`humans.txt`](https://humanstxt.org/)

and maybe even:

- [`hackers.txt`](https://medium.com/takeaway-tech/the-history-of-the-hackerstxt-and-securitytxt-files-95c0a3be43a9)
- [`credits.txt`](https://creditstxt.com/)

can live together.

### But what about `sitemap.xml` and `serviceworker.js` ?

So far, so good.

But what if, analagously, I want to have something like:

- `/.well-known/sitemaps/sitemap.xml`
- `/.well-known/serviceworkers/serviceworker.js`

I *know* I can use `.htaccess` to rewrite requests for `/sitemap.xml` and `/serviceworker.js`, but I also know that these files are **location-sensitive**.

That is, the directives in each of these files are *only supposed to apply to files*:

- *in the same folder*; and
- *in subfolders of that folder*

See:

> The location of a Sitemap file determines the set of URLs that can be
> included in that Sitemap. A Sitemap file located at
> http://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml can include any URLs starting
> with http://example.com/catalog/ but can not include URLs starting
> with http://example.com/images/.
>
> **Source:** https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location

and:

> The service worker will only catch requests from clients under the
> service worker's scope. [...] The max scope for a service worker is
> the location of the worker.
>
> **Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

But what *is* the ***sensitive location*** in this context?

Is it the "location" as it appears in the filepath request, or is it the *actual* filesystem location?

Comment: While there is merit to the argument that similar files should live in the same place, it is easier for somebody to understand what is going on on your server when files are found in their default locations.   If somebody new comes in and wants to add to your `robots.txt` they may have trouble locating it or try to create a new one assuming that one does not exist.

Comment: This is a fair point. But I've not described the rest of the setup. There's a `JSON` file on the back-end of the site which can be updated via a GUI (accessed from the site's _Control Pad_). Whenever _that_ `JSON` file on the back-end is updated, the file is parsed and the output from parsing the file is saved (to the root or wherever) as a `robots.txt`. This means the actual `robots.txt` file is never edited directly.

Comment: None of these files might exist on the server's file system, they could all be created and served directly by the web server software.

Comment: Excellent point, @curiousdannii. I've now got my head around the idea that the key requirement in all of this (for certain documents like `/robots.txt` and `/.well-known/security.txt`) is _only_ a correctly formatted **URL Path**. As such - and fairly ironically, given that I was originally setting out to find a way to put all protocol files and other meta documents in the `/.well-known/` folder - I've now ditched the `/.well-known/` folder entirely and moved all the meta documents into subfolders like `/.assets/theme/meta/protocols/` and `/.assets/theme/meta/sitemaps/`.

Comment: The sitemap rules you mention are not true in practice. You can put your sitemap anywhere and refer to any URLs in any directory (on the same domain).

Comment: Thanks, @DisgruntledGoat - this is important and noteworthy if you can cite evidence to back it up. (If you can, please do.) I know the same rules apply to PWA serviceworkers, in which context - I'm fairly certain - such rules can't be as easily ignored. But, again, please cite evidence if you know differently.

Comment: @Rounin I don’t know exactly what would count as “evidence”. I thought there was a question on here but I can’t find it now. But you can just put a sitemap in a random directory and submit it to Google Search Console and it will process it just fine.

Comment: Thanks. Sure. I can accept Google is doing this. By "evidence" I mean does such behaviour accord with the spec? Is there a document from Google or Mozilla (or from WHAT-WG or from W3C etc.) which describes when this is spec-conformant behaviour for user-agents? Or is Google (in this case) just behaving arbitrarily and / or opportunistically and may change its behaviour at any time without notice or warning, such that this behaviour can in no way be relied upon (and certainly not from other user-agents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it the location in the requested filepath, or the actual filesystem location?

The location is with regards to the requested URL-path (not strictly a "filepath"). The location of the file on the underlying server's filesystem is irrelevant and unknown to the user-agent making the request.

All requests to these files are client-side HTTP requests (ie. URLs). The same as all the other file types you've mentioned.

**UPDATE:**

> That is, the directives in each of these files are only supposed to
> apply to files:
>
> - in the same folder;
> - and in subfolders of that folder

What is perhaps confusing here is the use of the term "folder". It's not really a "folder" (which implies a physical directory on a filesystem), it's a "URL-path" - what you see in the browser's address bar. Unfortunately, "folder", "directory" and "file-path" get used a lot when describing URLs, but that is strictly incorrect. When you rewrite the request in `.htaccess`, you are rewriting the request from a URL-path to a file-path.

Comment: Thank you, @MrWhite. So, for clarification, a sitemap.xml at `https://example.com/.well-known/sitemaps/sitemap.xml` ***can*** include any URLs starting with `https://example.com/catalog/` (even though the sitemap in question resides in  `https://example.com/.well-known/sitemaps/`) _so long as_ that sitemap is ***requested*** from `https://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml`?

Comment: @Rounin Yes, that's right.

Comment: Great. Thanks very much for that clarification.

Comment: @Rounin You're welcome. Some of this confusion might come about from using the term "folder" to refer to a URL-path segment. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Rounin Consumers of these files have no way of knowing about your rewrite rules or where these files are stored on disk.   They can only know about the URL path from which they are requested.  The reason that the restrictions are relative to the URL path is that all the the requirements are enforced by the client and the client has no way to know anything except the URL path.